# Numpy, Is it possible to sum over specific elements of a matrix (2 dimensional array) given a list of indexes?

Tags: numpy

After some research, I could not use function *sum* of Numpy successfully to solve my problem. I give here a really basic example (the matrix I am targetting is huge as is the list of indexes, that's why I use Numpy):

I have a matrix

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
```

And a list of indexes

```
L = [ 2, 3, 0 ]
```

from which I need to compute:

```
A[2][3] + A[3][0]
```

So, more formally I need to compute the sum of `A[i][i+1]` for `i` in list `L`

And I need to do it as fast as possible (so, **no loop** allowed)

Best regards

Aymeric

Comment: If `A` is (2,4) shape, `A[2]` will produce an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to reshape `L` using `np.repeat` in the first place

```
L = tuple(np.repeat(L,2)[1:-1].reshape(-1,2).T)
```

Then, with this new `L`, you can do the summation directly

```
np.sum(A[L])
```

The full example

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
L = np.array([1,1,0])

L = tuple(np.repeat(L,2)[1:-1].reshape(-1,2).T)
np.sum(A[L])
```

A bigger example

```
A = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(929,929))
L = np.random.randint(0,928,size=928)

L = tuple(np.repeat(L,2)[1:-1].reshape(-1,2).T)
np.sum(A[L])
```

Comment: Hello, your idea is good, and it works for your given example, but when I use a bigger matrix it does not work. len(L) = 928, A.shape (929, 929), error saying *IndexError: too many indices for array*

Comment: Ok, I think I might have to use array instead of tuple for L

Comment: @ailauli69 I'm sorry, I forgot to transpose the indices in my original answer, please check out my updated post, maybe this time it is eligible as an accepted answer (not the previous one).